# Library plans for C++0x?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, c++11

Lately I've been getting very excited about the support for lambdas in VC2010. I'm slowly starting to grasp the full potential this feature has in transforming C++ into something alot better.

But then I realized that this potential greatly depends on main stream support of lambdas in day to day libraries like boost and QT.
Does anyone know if there are plans to extend these libraries with the new features of C++0x?

lambdas practically replace the need for boost::lambda and everything in boost that interacts with it.
QT could add support for lambdas in all of their container and maybe even as an alternative way of defining `SLOT`s

Comment: `boost::bind` targets another thing not being replaced by lambdas. `std::bind` will do its job of binding functions. Instead, lambdas will partially replace functionality in `boost::lambda` (and its successor, boost::phoenix, afaik). What lambdas currently can't do is the polymorphism of `boost::lambda`. The ability to create functions that work on any argument type: `_1++` increments any argument type, while `[](int &a) { a++; }` can only increment int. I heard now that concepts are out of C++, polymorphic lambdas are an option again.

Comment: @litb - that's interesting, do you have any links to material explaining why concepts were a roadblock to lambdas with type parameters?

Comment: I don't know of a paper that discusses it in detail, but i read that on usenet. I imagine, there should have been a way to say `requires Blah<T> [](T t) { ... }` or something like this to make the lambda's `operator()` template constrained. Another problem could be that in a constrained template you can only call other constrained templates to allow a template definition to be type-checked. So with a lambda having a simple unconstained templated `operator()`, you couldn't use that in a constrained template like this: `template<Identity T> void f(T t) { ([](u) { ... })(t); }`.

Comment: Now with concepts gone, these questions aren't to be solved anymore.

Comment: lambdas as slots will be such a wonderful thing one day. I can't remember how many times I've written one line slots or just connected one to test something out... saving all the work of writing a "normal" slot would be a great short cut.

Comment: ah, didn't know concepts blocked for that. Sounds like kicking them out was the right way to go (even if it's probably too late now to introduce polymorphic lambdas)

Comment: @litb - so what would be the use-case for introducing a new type parameter at the point of defining a lambda? To me the idea of a lambda is that you define them at the (only) point of use. I can see why (obviously) you'd want lambdas to depend on type parameters from the surrounding class or function, but that seems to work fine already (at least in MSVC++2010 beta 1). But if you want to define something reusable, you need to give it a name - and so you'd write class that overloads operator `()` as we've always done.

Comment: Actually I didn't even realise you could write `[](u) { ... }` and have the compiler figure out the type of `u` for you, so that may be where I'm getting lost. In any case, the workaround is to put `[](T u) { ... }` so is that really a big deal?

Comment: @Earwicker, well if you say `[](u) { ... }` then you have the same horrible and long error messages as you have today with templates, because the compiler does know nothing about "u". within constrained templates (the ones that have requirements clauses), you would need a `late_check { ... }` around the lambda then, to say the compiler *"oh, don't type-check this part: it's a lambda function which i don't know the type of 'u' for"*. Of course, this assumes the polymorphic lambda is implemented using the obvious templated `operator()`.

Comment: @Earwicker, well the `[](u) { ... }` syntax was made-up by me, to have some syntax for polymorphic lambdas. I guess another syntax could be `[](auto u) { ... }` or something. Or you could enhance it so you could say `template<typename T> [](T u, T u) { ... }` and could thus constraint it to have two parameters of the same type.

Comment: See this usenet post: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/364c4bd6dfb8e628

Comment: I see, that's why I got confused :) So in terms of what might be enabled now that concepts are out, are we basically talking about the convenience of having type inference on the parameters? Aside from that, I can't see what the advantage is, because the whole point of a lambda is that it isn't reusable, so it doesn't need to be parameterised. If you need it to be reusable, you give it a name, i.e. write an ordinary function (or class if it needs state).

Comment: @Earwicker, well i thought about it this way: `auto u = [](auto &p) { p = 0; }; int a; u(a); float b; u(b); /* a and b are zero now */`. Not sure whether this makes sense though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambdas already fit very well into existing libraries - anywhere that a function accepts a function object of a type given by a template parameter.

This is one of the great things about them - they're a classic example of a language feature that codifies existing practice in a nifty syntax.

Obviously the boost lambda library becomes redundant, but that means it doesn't require any new features to be added to it.

Comment: A comment from the downvoter might be interesting (but then again, it might not).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how usage of lambda depends on support by libraries. Lambdas eliminate the need to create many classes just to wrap different small algorithms and neatly fit together with other language/library features (`std::function` comes to mind). Wherever you used to pass either a function object or a function pointer, lambdas can be used, too.

So they mainly add another alternative for making use of existing code and libraries. The only way I can see for libraries to better support lambda is use more functional-style approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are such libraries are going to wait until there's proper compiler support for the relevant C++0x features , and not bother much with it until the mainstream compilers do support it. Don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT true, you cannot replace boost::lambda with C++0x lambda. See [here](http://uint32t.blogspot.com/2009/05/using-c0x-lambda-to-replace-boost-bind.html) for some reasons (about boost bind, but I think most of it transfers)

Also, @daniel [this](http://uint32t.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-boost-bind-and-boost-function.html) might help you get started using lambda functions/boost bind for slots. It makes my life incredibly easy.

Additionally, @litb from my sources, lambdas are not going to be changed (argh)

Comment: regarding the ugly problem of closing over a loop variable and having to make a copy. Instead use `for_each` to loop through the `vector<int>`. Pass it a lambda to act as the "loop block", i.e. `for_each(d.begin(), d.end(), [&](int i) { /* loop body goes here */ });` Now that `i` can now be safely captured by value as it is already a copy, and so inside the loop you'd say `funcs.push_back([=]() { return i + 5; });`. The same problem/solution arises in C# and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries use standard function pointers for callbacks. C++0x lambdas can be used as function pointers, so most libraries wouldn't need to be modified. Other libraries use templates so they can take any callable object (e.g. `std::foreach` wouldn't need to be modified).

The only other C++0x feature that I can think of that libraries might change to is using strongly typed `enums`. Also, libraries might start to use `extern` templates to reduce compilation times.

Comment: r-value references will (or should) have a big impact - a lot of libraries have classes that serve as wrappers around resources that are expensive to construct, and the addition of move operations will instantly speed up many programs written with such libraries (or make correct programs much more readable).

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about R-value references. I'm guessing they would be used a lot in libraries like Boost, but not so much in application oriented libraries like Qt. Also, in most cases, it will not break the interface, so you won't ever have to worry about them (except using them in your own code).

Comment: You cannot assign the result of a lambda expression to a function pointer.

Comment: @sellibitze: An old comment, I know, but now you can if the lambda is stateless.